# how to draw a color filled circle in objective with number in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, core-animation

I am looking to the below thing in Objective c.

I thought of having a black color rounder image and trasparent background color label on top of that

so that it appears like the below image

[image]

Is there any other easy way to do this ?

Comment: Using a `UILabel` or `UIButton` (or event a `UIView`) and changing the corner radius of the `CALayer`...as an idea

Comment: UIbutton would be good

Comment: "Easy" is in the eye of the beholder. Personally I would just draw the circle and the number in code; to me, that's easy. On the other hand, if you really want to do no work at all, just use an existing glyph, like this: ➍

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    label.backgroundColor = .black
    label.textColor = .white
    label.text = "4"
    label.clipsToBounds = true
    label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.width/2
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer.